# XML transforming in other format with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new in XSLT and I am very confused. I have to solve the following problem.

```
<root>
<level_1 name="Level 1">
    <level_2 name="Level 2">
        <level_3 name="Level 3">
            <level_4 name="Level 4">
                <level_5 name="Level 5">
                    <level_6 name="level_6 1" />
                    <level_6 name="level_6 2" />
                </level_5>
            </level_4>
        </level_3>
    </level_2>     
</level_1>
</root>
```

I want to transform this file in a form that is not deep nested such above.
So it has to look like:

```
<root>
<level_1 name="level_1">
    <level_2 name="level_2"/>
    <level_3 name="level_3"/>
    <level_4 name="level_4"/>
    <level_5 name="level_5"/>
    <level_6 name="level_6 1"/>
</level_1>
<level_1 name="level_1">
    <level_2 name="level_2"/>
    <level_3 name="level_3"/>
    <level_4 name="level_4"/>
    <level_5 name="level_5"/>
    <level_6 name="level_6 2"/>
</level_1>
</root>
```

Now all levels are nested in `<level_1>`. Furthermore in the source XML there are two `<level_6>` elements. In my target XML these two elements are in different `<level_1>` elements. 
I have no idea because I am new in XSLT.

Please with explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, one example input and output does not constitute a specification. We need to know not only what the stylesheet should do with this input, but also what it should do with other inputs. For example, what should it do with an input where the leaf nodes are not all on the same level.

However, if the requirement is to expand a path for each leaf element (an element that has no children) then you could try this (in XSLT 3.0):

```
<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:variable name="root" select="."/>
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="//*[not(*)]">
      <xsl:variable name="ancestors" select="ancestor-or-self::* except $root"/>
      <xsl:copy select="head($ancestors)">
         <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="tail($ancestors)">
           <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
           </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```